# search result on the basis of category and colors

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I have 4 mysql tables as follows..

**Products** (id,sku,name,color_id,description,excerpt)

**Colors** (color_name,color_id)

**Categories** (categ_name,categ_id)

**Product_Categories** (pid,cid)

Now I want to perform search operation.Currently my search query is based on product id,sku,description or color_id.

My query is in codeigniter as follows....

```
$color_id   =   0;
        $this->db->select('color_id');
        $this->db->where('LOWER(color_name)',strtolower($term));
        $color_row  =   $this->db->get('product_colors')->row();
        if($color_row)
            $color_id   =   $color_row->color_id;

$this->db->select('*, LEAST(IFNULL(NULLIF(saleprice, 0), price), price) as sort_price', false);
        //this one gets just the ones we need.
        $this->db->where('enabled', 1);
        $this->db->where('(name LIKE "%'.$term.'%" OR description LIKE "%'.$term.'%" OR excerpt LIKE "%'.$term.'%" OR sku LIKE "%'.$term.'%" OR color='.$color_id.')');
```

This is working absolutely fine.But I want to search on category basis too. For example I want to search like **"Red Shoes"** where Red is the color and shoes is the category name.

Please tell me how to build query for this.

It will be a great help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: No, please tell us how you'd build the query for this and we'll help if you encounter any problems.

Comment: @markus thanks for negative but I dont know what query needs to be written here.I have no idea about this type of searching (Red shows,Brown Jacket etc)

Comment: Well, start finding out, if nothing else by trial and error. What have you tried so far? How did it fail? What are your thoughts about how this could be solved? You need to show that you're willing to contribute instead of just letting others do your job for you.

Comment: @markus what can I do I already did I am searching on all the basis except category. Only this one is remaining.

Comment: normally the color name for a product is not going to change - so consider having it be part of the product table. you can still use a separate table for choosing the color name when you create the product.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one by joining all your tables

```
$term=$_POST['your search field name'];
$keyword=explode(" ",$term);
$this->db->select('p.*');
$this->db->from('Products p');
$this->db->join('Product_Categories pc', 'p.id = pc.pid','LEFT');
$this->db->join('Categories c', 'pc.cid = c.categ_id','LEFT');
$this->db->join('Colors co', 'p.color_id = co.color_id','LEFT');
$this->db->where('p.enabled', 1);

foreach($keyword as $k){
$this->db->or_where('p.id =', $k);//or_where
$this->db->like('p.sku', $k);
$this->db->like('p.description', $k);//or_like
$this->db->like('co.color_name', $k);
$this->db->like('c.categ_name', $k);

}

$this->db->group_by("p.id");
```

[**Active Record Class**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS JOIN 
Product_Categories ON PRODUCTS.id = Product_Categories.pid
JOIN Categories on Categories.categ_id = Product_Categories.cid
JOIN Colors ON Colors.color_id = Products.color_id
WHERE categ_name = 'Shoes' AND Colors='Red';
```

Comment: danip thanks for your answer but I also need to search on product name,desc,excerpt,sku, color name etc.. I need to use OR in all this... Please see my query and add your query in that . It is in codeigniter. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

get the category name first like
 $categ_name   =   $categ_row-categ_name;
 $color_name   =   $color_row-color_name;

in conditions put Colors.color_name like '$color_name' and Categories.categ_name like '$categ_name'